# ZF3 Doctrine Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion

Tags: zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm

In my specialisme entity i want to join al column and display rows from specialisme with the joined column, but i get error: Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion

In specialisme entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $fullname;

//...

/**
 * Returns fullname.
 * @return string     
 */
public function getFullName() 
{
    return $this->fullname;
}
```

In controller:

```
    public function indexAction()
    {
    //Array met alle user samenstellen
    $users = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Specialisme::class)->findBy([], ['id'=>'ASC']);

    //Users doorgeven aan view model        
    return new ViewModel([
        'users' => $users
    ]);

    return new ViewModel();
}
```

View:

```
<tr>
    <th>Naam</th>
    <th>Specialisme</th>
    <th>Sub-specialisme</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>

<tr>
    <td>f</td>
    <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($user->getId()); ?></td>
    <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($user->getFullName()); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It gives back the object,so i have to use the method of the referencing object:

$user->getBeschikbaarheid()->getOpZoekNaar());